# SQL result differ but no error

Tags: c#, sql-server

There's something I don't get. I tried to get a result with a SQL query in C# but it's not working so I tried it in SQL Server Management Studio. My first attempt was the  first query which works as supposed to, but to be as close as how I wrote it in C#, I did the second one but, as in my C# app, it returns no result.

Here is the code:

```
select quincid 
from itemsquinc
where code_produit like '%MPB79 - 4 1/2 x 4 - 652 (26D)%'
```

and

```
declare @test nvarchar(max)
set @test = '"MPB79 - 4 1/2 x 4 - 652 (26D)"'

select quincid 
from itemsquinc
where code_produit like '%@test%'
```

Can someone explain me why the second one is not returning any results?

Thanks

Comment: Why the double quotes in @test?

Comment: Concatenate: `'%' + @test + '%'` & as mentioned lose the `"` as  they are in your working example.

Comment: One has double quotes and the other doesnt?

Comment: Thanks guys, as you spot it, the double quote and concatenate do the job !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching on the literal @test not variable @test

```
declare @test nvarchar(max) set @test = 'MPB79 - 4 1/2 x 4 - 652 (26D)'

select quincid  from itemsquinc where code_produit like '%' + @test + '%'
```